# Lego 7670 has two different box designs?

Tags: star-wars, lego-store

Does Lego 7670 (Hailfire Droid and Spider Droid) have two different colored boxes? I am seeing two different boxes on Ebay and other sites. One is a white clone wars box, and the other is a dark red and black Darth Vader box. Why are there two boxes? Also I saw that on Ebay, that the white ones were cheaper and used, but the black ones are usually New and if they are used, they Don't have boxes. Is one more valuable than the other?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it seems there are two different boxes for [7670 Hailfire Droid & Spider Droid](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=7670), but it seems the box is the only difference, so if you just want the pieces ignore which box they're selling and buy the cheapest. :)